# Border around table-head

Tags: html, css, html-table, position, border

The problem is that the border I made for the `thead` isn't following the rules that I made for it - the position, which is moved down, and a little to the left. How can I move the border so it "sticks" to the thead?

http://jsfiddle.net/GRf9v/188/

Comment: Might seem odd without further reading into it, but tfoot should always be above the tbody in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid using positioning in a table. Positioning is intended for block elements, not tabular data as such. I don't think it is helping you achieve what you want in this instance.

Is this closer to what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/GRf9v/189/

This should not be a table. See updated answer: http://jsfiddle.net/GRf9v/190/

Hopefully that will help you get going.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what i'm looking for. More likes this: http://i.imgur.com/H2F80.png
I know I put the footer inside the head, but it was the only way I could figure out how to put a box in a box.

Comment: That doesn't look anywhere near a table. Is there any reason why you're using a table? Otherwise you could search for tutorials on coding without tables.

Comment: Not really, no. I used a table generator, as I thought it was the appropriate way of making boxes for text. Can you redirect me to a better place? It's really helpful!

Comment: @user1694558 See my updated answer. Tables are not for layout, they are for tabular data representation only. Good luck! :)

Comment: Didn't seee that one! Thank you very much, Nix! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you opt in not using tables for that, you may check this out. 
http://jsfiddle.net/athanph/6hhPK/

Comment: That looks very nice! Thank you very much.